# Unable to instantiate chaincode in Hyperledger fabric 1.3 when using couchdb option in fabric-samples

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm following the private data tutorial from here:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/private_data_tutorial.html

When I run the byfn.sh script like so:

```
./byfn.sh up -s couchdb
```

from the `first-network` folder I am able to get to the point where the network is installed, but it dies on the instantiation.

The error I'm getting is one of two error, either this:

```
Instantiating chaincode on peer0.org2...
+ peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n mycc -l golang -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a","100","b","200"]}' -P 'AND ('\''Org1MSP.peer'\'','\''Org2MSP.peer'\'')'
+ res=1
+ set +x
2018-12-17 17:45:57.641 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2018-12-17 17:45:57.641 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
Error: error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Chaincode instantiation on peer0.org2 on channel 'mychannel' failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========
```

or this:

```
Instantiating chaincode on peer0.org2...
+ peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n mycc -l golang -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a","100","b","200"]}' -P 'AND ('\''Org1MSP.peer'\'','\''Org2MSP.peer'\'')'
+ res=1
+ set +x
2018-12-17 17:58:36.995 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2018-12-17 17:58:36.995 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg error starting container: error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "/opt/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: signal: killed
"
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Chaincode instantiation on peer0.org2 on channel 'mychannel' failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========
```

If I don't use the `-s couchdb` paramter, it will work with no problems.

I'm running this on Ubuntu 18.04 and all the pre-req's are installed. Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?

UPDATE:
Here are the some of the docker logs for peer0.org2

```
2018-12-17 20:29:55.296 UTC [gossip/gossip] handleMessage -> WARN 047 Message GossipMessage: tag:CHAN_OR_ORG state_info:<timestamp:<inc_num:1545078583282595060 seq_num:1545078592853991651 > pki_id:"9\350\367\340\200G\2306\360!\r\342\221$\013O\315\377~\303'\263\224\234\323OtS\266^Y\204" channel_MAC:"7oV\232\272;n\213c\264\364+d\323\274\234\370\253\277\337\375\255\375\003\240>=\007\026\323\317\316" properties:<ledger_heigh
t:2 > > , Envelope: 98 bytes, Signature: 70 bytes isn't valid
2018-12-17 20:29:55.873 UTC [gossip/privdata] StoreBlock -> INFO 048 [mychannel] Received block [2] from buffer
2018-12-17 20:29:55.894 UTC [gossip/gossip] JoinChan -> INFO 049 Joining gossip network of channel mychannel with 2 organizations
2018-12-17 20:29:55.904 UTC [gossip/gossip] learnAnchorPeers -> INFO 04a Learning about the configured anchor peers of Org1MSP for channel mychannel : [{peer0.org1.example.com 7051}]
2018-12-17 20:29:55.904 UTC [gossip/gossip] learnAnchorPeers -> INFO 04b Learning about the configured anchor peers of Org2MSP for channel mychannel : [{peer0.org2.example.com 7051}]
2018-12-17 20:29:55.904 UTC [gossip/gossip] learnAnchorPeers -> INFO 04c Anchor peer with same endpoint, skipping connecting to myself
2018-12-17 20:29:55.905 UTC [committer/txvalidator] Validate -> INFO 04d [mychannel] Validated block [2] in 31ms
2018-12-17 20:29:55.990 UTC [kvledger] CommitWithPvtData -> INFO 04e [mychannel] Committed block [2] with 1 transaction(s) in 83ms (state_validation=0ms block_commit=19ms state_commit=55ms)
2018-12-17 20:30:00.051 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 04f [][9f6b48cc] Entry chaincode: name:"lscc"
2018-12-17 20:30:00.074 UTC [couchdb] CreateDatabaseIfNotExist -> INFO 050 Created state database mychannel_lscc
2018-12-17 20:30:00.076 UTC [lscc] executeInstall -> INFO 051 Installed Chaincode [mycc] Version [1.0] to peer
2018-12-17 20:30:00.076 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 052 [][9f6b48cc] Exit chaincode: name:"lscc"  (25ms)
2018-12-17 20:30:00.169 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 053 [mychannel][9656eaad] Entry chaincode: name:"lscc"
2018-12-17 20:30:00.204 UTC [golang-platform] GenerateDockerBuild -> INFO 054 building chaincode with ldflagsOpt: '-ldflags "-linkmode external -extldflags '-static'"'
2018-12-17 20:30:00.204 UTC [golang-platform] GenerateDockerBuild -> INFO 055 building chaincode with tags:
2018-12-17 20:31:04.525 UTC [gossip/discovery] getDeadMembers -> WARN 056 Haven't heard from [242 171 107 244 150 35 129 53 213 6 101 53 106 212 63 160 250 230 42 248 213 246 136 122 133 191 100 41 243 29 153 133] for 27.909647593s
2018-12-17 20:31:44.018 UTC [gossip/discovery] getDeadMembers -> WARN 057 Haven't heard from [73 47 250 236 221 95 181 79 20 161 111 61 168 177 21 136 172 73 40 70 233 52 227 86 153 143 180 44 99 176 246 248] for 1m19.691918704s
2018-12-17 20:31:44.018 UTC [gossip/discovery] getDeadMembers -> WARN 058 Haven't heard from [57 232 247 224 128 71 152 54 240 33 13 226 145 36 11 79 205 255 126 195 39 179 148 156 211 79 116 83 182 94 89 132] for 1m19.695671013s
2018-12-17 20:31:44.018 UTC [gossip/discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 059 Entering [[242 171 107 244 150 35 129 53 213 6 101 53 106 212 63 160 250 230 42 248 213 246 136 122 133 191 100 41 243 29 153 133] [73 47 250 236 221 95 181 79 20 161 111 61 168 177 21 136 172 73 40 70 233 52 227 86 153 143 180 44 99 176 246 248] [57 232 247 224 128 71 152 54 240 33 13 226 145 36 11 79 205 255 126 195 39 179 148 156 211 79 116 8
3 182 94 89 132]]
2018-12-17 20:31:44.018 UTC [gossip/discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 05a Closing connection to Endpoint: peer1.org2.example.com:7051, InternalEndpoint: peer1.org2.example.com:7051, PKI-ID: [242 171 107 244 150 35 129 53 213 6 101 53 106 212 63 160 250 230 42 248 213 246 136 122 133 191 100 41 243 29 153 133], Metadata: []
2018-12-17 20:31:44.018 UTC [gossip/discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 05b Closing connection to Endpoint: peer0.org1.example.com:7051, InternalEndpoint: , PKI-ID: [73 47 250 236 221 95 181 79 20 161 111 61 168 177 21 136 172 73 40 70 233 52 227 86 153 143 180 44 99 176 246 248], Metadata: []
2018-12-17 20:31:44.018 UTC [gossip/discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 05c Closing connection to Endpoint: peer1.org1.example.com:7051, InternalEndpoint: , PKI-ID: [57 232 247 224 128 71 152 54 240 33 13 226 145 36 11 79 205 255 126 195 39 179 148 156 211 79 116 83 182 94 89 132], Metadata: []
2018-12-17 20:31:44.018 UTC [gossip/discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 05d Exiting
2018-12-17 20:31:45.042 UTC [chaincode-platform] func1 -> ERRO 05e Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "/opt/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: signal: killed
"
2018-12-17 20:31:45.046 UTC [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 05f Error building images: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "/opt/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: signal: killed
"
2018-12-17 20:31:45.047 UTC [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 060 Image Output:
********************

********************
2018-12-17 20:31:45.061 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 061 [mychannel][9656eaad] Exit chaincode: name:"lscc"  (104891ms)
2018-12-17 20:31:45.061 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 062 [mychannel][9656eaad] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "/opt/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: signal: killed
"
error starting container
error starting container
```

Comment: the peer log for peer0.org2 may be helpful. do a `docker ps -a -f name=peer0.org2` and put the output in `docker logs {output}`to see peer logs.

Comment: I just added the peer0.org2 logs to the question. I looked at them earlier and I'm not seeing anything useful in there, maybe you can gather more insight from them than me.

Comment: one possible reason is that maybe the images you have are not current , or the system is running out of memory.

Comment: thanks.. The box i'm using is rather small. I'll try it again on a larger box to see if that helps.

Comment: looks like that was it! I was running a t2.micro instance on AWS. After upgrading it to a t2.medium it now works. Thanks for  your help!

Comment: Great! I will add my comment as a answer for future readers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `Error returned from build: 1 "/opt/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: signal: killed` indicates its a memory limitation issue, the network needs more resource to run. (see comments under the question)